# API java receive JWT from Angular application connected to Azure B2C

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

While working on an Angular App connected to Azure B2C, I received the next exception while calling the Java API.

THE EXCEPTION
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The issuer: 'https://ABC.b2clogin.com/e761f276-37f8-499d-aaec-47801cdea4d1/v2.0/' is not registered in trusted issuer repository, so cannot create JWSKeySelector.", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

or

WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

However, the app functioned properly when I tried using the test curl with the client credentials.

I was reviewing the issuer generation process and noticed a difference.

When I used the client's credentials, the "iss" value was set to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/e761f276-37f8-499d-aaec-47801cdea4d1/v2.0".
However, when I used my Angular app, the "iss" value changed to "https://ABC.b2clogin.com/e761f276-37f8-499d-aaec-47801cdea4d1/v2.0/".

I used the samples.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory-b2c/aad-b2c-resource-server

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/tree/main/4.%20Spring%20Framework%20Web%20App%20Tutorial/3-Authorization-II/protect-web-api